# BigQuery: Credentials asked in the automated job

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a python application/job which is pushing the dataframe to BigQuery. However that job is failing because evidently it is asking for the credentials as show below:

> Please visit this URL to authorize this application:

As this is an automated job, I can't click the link and submit the code. Is there any other way to pass the authorization?

I have already setup the service account key in my environment variable / bashrc.

**Code**:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService


class Transmitter:

    def __init__(self):
            self.blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='xxxx',
                                                 account_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
            self.dataset_id = 'xxxx'
            self.jobQuery = "select JobID, EmailName from xxxxx group by JobID, EmailName"
            self.keyDf = pd.read_csv('jobKeys.csv')

    def toBigQJobs(self):

        jDf = pd.read_gbq(self.jobQuery, project_id='xxxx', dialect='standard')

        jDf['Type'] = 'C'
        jDf['Category'] = 'other'
        for index, row in jDf.iterrows():
            for indexA, rowA in self.keyDf.iterrows():
                    if rowA['Key'] in row['EmailName']:
                            jDf.loc[index, 'Category'] = rowA['Category']
                            jDf.loc[index, 'Type'] = rowA['Type']
                            break

        jDf.to_gbq(destination_table='xxxx', project_id='xxxx',
                    if_exists='replace')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    objTransmitter = Transmitter()

    objTransmitter.toBigQJobs()
```

Comment: You've obviously not set up the service account properly. Please share your code and how you setting/using the service account.

Comment: I just went to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python and then created the new service account, generated the json key. Then I put that Json key in the path variable. Am I missing any step? Just to clarify, it dint ask the credentials everytime actually but once. Although I am not sure how to click that link to get the Auth code because my job is configured automatically.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Just now added. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see in your code where you are setting up the service account. Where are you doing this? Have you read this: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

Comment: I guess one can set the path of the JSON key in the bashrc. I have done that just like this: export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"

Is there anything to be added in he code apart from this?

Comment: The application is running smoothly if I manually execute it by giving python filename.py but when I execute it by configuring a job in Azure batch, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Add environment variable through os.environ and it worked.